# Is it possible to give Balance for transactions?

Tags: pallet, balances

I know that transactions require certain fees to ensure the correctness of the network, but i was wondering if it is possible to do the reverse operation. I want to give users that send transactions Balance.

Comment: I think that's technically possible, but why? This has the same ramifications as having no fees (e.g. DoS) but it also adds incentive to do that on top.

Comment: I'm not thinking of a decentralized network, I was thinking about a private network where there are already well known addresses and if they send transactions with some information, It is already assumed to be correct. On a decentralized network I guess it will require some validators to ensure that the information is correct and later on award the providers and also the validators, but its not the case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The transaction fees are charged by the [`ChargeTransactionPayment`](https://crates.parity.io/pallet_transaction_payment/struct.ChargeTransactionPayment.html) [signed extension](https://docs.substrate.io/v3/concepts/tx-pool/#signed-extensions). I don't believe you could configure that thing to "charge" negative amounts. But I think you can just reimplement your own `SignedExtension`, maybe potentially based on top of that, that will reward each transactor and replace/add to your signed extras (like [here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/44e2616153caca7a16e148159ebd66cdeb702310/runtime/polkadot/src/lib.rs#L1480)).